# How to search addresses using Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a simple app where I have 100 records of customer with address. The requirement is to have a field for radius and address. The two fields will become the parameters to search customers.

For example: 
Radius = 500 miles and Address = New York

Results should be customers 500 miles near New York.

Answer (score 1):

For the math you need the harvesine formula or a spatial index when it's ok to find a bounding box. There are many examples for the harvesine formula on the internet and stackoverflow. A spatial index is usually a bounding box, rectangle or a square and can use a space filling curve to reduce the dimension and improve query speed. Read about spatial index: http://www.blog.notdot.net/2009/11/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Spatial-indexing-with-Quadtrees-and-Hilbert-Curves.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by marking a position in New york, maybe a default position given by the search in the text input or making the geocoding, passing the string with the direction, once you marked that point you draw a circle  with the radius that you need, and when you draw this Circle you calculate the distace between each record of your customer addres with the center, if the result it's equal or less than 500 miles add a marker with the customer record.

For example the geocoding (assuming the autocomplete) would be something like

```
<input type="text" id="prueba" size="50">
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:800px;height:550px"> </div>

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
     var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17); 
      }
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
}
```

Now after set the point that would be your center draw a circle and calculate the distance between the center and the each record position

```
var populationOptions = {
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    center: marker.getPosition(),
    radius: 1000,
    editable: true
};

circle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
```

From here you could calculate the distance

```
var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(circleCenter, yourPosition);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to do the distance calculation on the database.  Assuming you have a relational database and each customer address record has lat / long...  You could geocode the input address for lat / long then use a SQL query to calculate distance between the input location and your customers.  Then filter the query results by the given radius.  From the query results it's a matter of plotting the filtered customers on the map.

There are a few [posts on S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549237/sql-query-to-pull-locations-based-on-distance-from-lat-lng-in-linq2sql)O on calculating distance from lat / long using SQL.

You can use the `google.maps.Geocoder` to geocode the lat / long of the given address.